# TSQL -- how does optimizer deal with joins with unused tables

Tags: t-sql, optimization, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

**TSQL -- how does optimizer deal with joins with unused tables**

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col1, table2.col2  -- etc.
FROM dbo.table1
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2
on (table1.id = table2.id)
LEFT JOIN dbo.table3
on (table1.id = table3.id)
```

In the simple example above it is obvious that table 3 isn't needed, however more  intricate cases can exist.

**Question:**  Is the TSQL query optimizer able to determine that the JOIN with table 3 isn't needed?  If so, would it potentially miss other optimizations for more complex queries, if table3 wasn't manually removed from the query?

I use SSMS 14.017 with an underlying SQL database of select @@version = Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, query optimizer could skip table3 because it is not referenced in SELECT list and the join condition is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so there is no filtering.

---

Related: [10 Cool SQL Optimisations That do not Depend on the Cost Model by Lukas Eder](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/#top3):

- Unneeded Table Accesses
- JOIN Elimination

[JOIN Elimination: An Essential Optimiser Feature for Advanced SQL Usage](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/01/join-elimination-an-essential-optimiser-feature-for-advanced-sql-usage/)

Comment: Any thoughts on:  If so, would it potentially miss other optimizations for more complex queries, if table3 wasn't manually removed from the query?

Comment: @JosephDoggie Modern query optimizers could be very "clever". As a rule of thumb, yes if you see that some condtions are impossible/unecessary then you should remove them manually.